# How can I remove characters in a string after a specific special character (~) in snowflake sql?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am using Snowflake SQL. I would like to remove characters from a string after a special character `~`. How can I do that?

here is the whole scenario. Let me explain. I do have a string like 'CK#123456~fndkjfgdjkg'. Now, i want only the number after #.And not anything after ~. This is number length varies for that field value. It might be 1 or 5 or 3. And i want to add the condition in where class where this number is equal to check_num from other table after joining. I am trying REGEXP_SUBSTR(A.SRC_TXT, '(?<=CK#)(.+?\b)') = C.CHK_NUM in the where condition. I am getting the error as 'No repititive argument after ?'

Comment: What do you did so far? Could you share some code please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex for this

```
-- To remove just the character after a ~
select regexp_replace('fo~o bar','~.', '');
-- returns 'fo bar'

--If you want to keep the ~
select regexp_replace('fo~o bar','~.', '~');
-- returns 'fo~ bar'

--If you want to remove everything after the ~
select regexp_replace('fo~o bar','~.*', '');
--returns 'fo'
```

If you need to remove other specific character sets after a ~, you can probably do this with a slightly more complicated regex, but I'd need examples of your desired input/output to help with that.

**EDIT for updated question**

This regex replace should get what you need.

```
select regexp_replace('CK#123456~fndkjfgdjkg','CK#(\\d*)~.*', '\\1');
-- returns 123456
```

`(\\d*)` gets ANY number of digits in a row, and the `\\1` causes it to replace the match with what was in the first set of parenthesis, which is your list of digits. the `CK#` and `~.*` are there to make sure the whole string gets matched and replaced.

If the `CK#` can vary as well, you can use `.*?` like this.

```
select regexp_replace('ABCD123HI#123456~fndkjfgdjkg','.*?#(\\d*)~.*', '\\1')
-- returns 123456
```

Comment: If you need to remove all the characters add a `*` after the `.` to indicate zero or more characters.  Ex.
> select regexp_replace($1,'~.*', '') from values ('fo~o'),('fo~xyz');

Comment: Thank you. This is working. But here is the whole scenario. Let me explain. I do have a string like 'CK#123456~fndkjfgdjkg'. Now, i want only the number after #.And not anything after ~. This is number length varies for that field value. It might be 1 or 5 or 3. And i want to add the condition in where class where this number is equal to check_num from other table after joining. I am trying REGEXP_SUBSTR(A.SRC_TXT, '(?<=CK#)(.+?\b)') = C.CHK_NUM in the where condition. I am getting the error as 'No repititive argument after ?'. Please help me out.

Comment: Your error is a syntax error with the first question mark. Both `(` and `?` are special characters and `?` doesn't work after a special character.

`select regexp_replace('CK#123456~fndkjfgdjkg','CK#(\\d*)~.*', '\\1'); ` Should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like the following, easy enough but not as cool as RegEx type of functions.

```
set my_string='fooo~12345';
set search_for_me = '~';
SELECT SUBSTR($my_string, 1, DECODE(position($search_for_me, $my_string), 0, length($my_string), position($search_for_me, $my_string)));
```

I hope this helps...Rich

Answer (score 0):

It looks like lookahead and lookbehinds are ***not*** supported in REGEXP functions, they seem to work in the PATTERN clause of a LIST command.  Snowflake documentation makes no mention either way of lookahead or lookbehinds.

In your example:

- It seems that the query engine is looking for that repeating argument, where you are attempting a lookbehind
- You have not specified what you wanted extracted.  You have two capture groups, but in this scenario everything would be returned
- Since you are looking to remove everything after `~` you have a delimiter, why not use it in your `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function?

Try the following:

```
SELECT $1,REGEXP_SUBSTR($1,'\\w+#(.+?)~',1,1,'is',1) 
FROM VALUES 
('CK#123456~fndkjfgdjkg')
,('QH#128fklj924~fndkjfgdjkg')
;
```

This looks for:

- One or more word characters
- Followed by `#`
- Capturing one or more characters upto and ***not*** including `~`
- Returns the characters within the capture group

You can change the `.+?` to `\\d+?` to make sure the pattern is only digits.  **Backslashes must be escaped with a backslash.**

The descriptions for each argument of the function can be found here:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html

Answer (score 0):

You could check this!!

select substr('CK#123456~fndkjfgdjkg',4,6) from dual;

OUTPUT
123456

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/substr.html